# What colour is a mix of two perfectly proportioned complementary colours?

Tags: color, color-theory

I am still on my journey in colour. I'm currently sitting at my desk so I'm unable to test the following myself: if I add a colour's complementary colour to "meet in the middle", as it were, would they just be brown? Are they tertiary?

I understand now that it reduces the saturation.

Comment: Hi Jamie Hutber, a mix between two complementary colors are called *broken colors*, see [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/114049/120647) at graphicdesign.stackexchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the answers in your other question ([Why do complementary colours desaturate each other?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/6209/why-do-complementary-colours-desaturate-each-other)) and the link in the comment by *Danielillo* address, **it will in theory be a perfect grey**: the complementary colours will have complementary temperature and value, so, after mixing, any pair of complementary colours will have the same perfectly neutral grey.

Of course, concerning the 'analogue' arts, **in practice, other factors weigh in, like the quality and opacity of the pigment, and its coarseness**. This will make the mixing harder, the proportions variable, and in most cases causes an overtone of the stronger colour.